# Need to print a new column for Panda data frame

Tags: python

I am using the following code to print ratio by applying a function, but am getting the following errors.

**Code**

```
import investpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

def main(stock1_name, stock2_name):
    stock1 = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock=stock1_name,country='india', from_date='01/01/2020',to_date='08/03/2021')
    stock2 = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock=stock2_name,country='india', from_date='01/01/2020',to_date='08/03/2021')
    new_df = pd.merge(stock1, stock2, on='Date')
    new_df = new_df.drop(['Open_x', 'High_x', 'Low_x', 'Volume_x', 'Currency_x', 'Low_y','Volume_y', 'Currency_y', 'Open_y', 'High_y'], axis = 1)
    new_df['ratio'] = np.log10(new_df['Close_x']/new_df['Close_y'])
    return new_df
    x = main("IOC","HPCL")
print(x)
```

**Error**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c17535375449> in <module>
     12     return new_df
     13     x = main("IOC","HPCL")
---> 14 print(x)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct? `x = main("IOC","HPCL")` needs to be called outside the function `main`

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your question first.

Comment: seems correct to me and if I run this without new_df['ratio' then it runs without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are calling `x = main("IOC","HPCL")` inside the function `main`
2. This makes `x` defined only inside the scope of the function `main`
3. When you call print(x) outside function `main` the interpreter throws error, as it should, that `x` is not defined

Does this correction solve the issue:

```
import investpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

def main(stock1_name, stock2_name):
    stock1 = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock=stock1_name,country='india', from_date='01/01/2020',to_date='08/03/2021')
    stock2 = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock=stock2_name,country='india', from_date='01/01/2020',to_date='08/03/2021')
    new_df = pd.merge(stock1, stock2, on='Date')
    new_df = new_df.drop(['Open_x', 'High_x', 'Low_x', 'Volume_x', 'Currency_x', 'Low_y','Volume_y', 'Currency_y', 'Open_y', 'High_y'], axis = 1)
    new_df['ratio'] = np.log10(new_df['Close_x']/new_df['Close_y'])
    return new_df

x = main("IOC","HPCL") # Edit moving this line outside the function main()
print(x)
```

Comment: Yes, Great help mate. Appreciated !!

Comment: @alokbehria, You're welcome mate, you can accept if it solved the issue. [When someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)